# How to make array to comma seperated correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like `arr = ["1000","2000"].`

I am converting this into comma separated value and then adding to my url.

Here I am converting to comma separated.

```
arr = arr.toLocaleString();
```

In my url, In chrome it is coming correctly but in IE it is coming `%` before value.

```
Chrome : /1001,2000/
    IE : /1001,%2000/
```

Url in IE is wrong. Anybody help me how to fix this.

Extra percentage is coming in url while checking in iE.

Comment: try `arr.join();` instead of `arr.toLocaleString();`

Comment: and using arr.join(',') ,gives the same bug?

Comment: Are you sure the space is not being url encoded as %20? That is, aren't you seeing /1001,%200000/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to join all elements of array into string ,and [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) it, like:

```
var arr = ["1000","2000"],
    str = arr.join(","),
    encodedStr = encodeURIComponent(str); // "1000%2C2000"
```

Comment: What is the problem though?